# Поиск по базе mysql на php

Tags: php, mysql

Стоит задача сделать поиск в базе  через php

```
<div>
    <form action="index1.php" target="_blank" method="get" >
    <input name="mdescr" placeholder="Адресс ОНУ" value="" maxlength="17">
    <input class="find" type ="submit" value ="Искать">
     </form>
</div>
```

В Форме надо вводить к примеру 5 символов и что бы оно по базе в по определенному полю искало все совпадения и выводил. Подключение к базе сделал и выборку с базы по нужному полю так же сделал, вся проблема в добивании текста.
будь те добры скинуть какой то пример или натолкнуть на мысль.

Comment: Используйте в запросе к БД оператор `LIKE` например `LIKE '%$keywords%'`

Comment: или `CONTAINS`. Что скорее всего будет быстрее.